# Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout

Tags: c#, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

These are my structures

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DeptDetails
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int depid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short noemp;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public empDetails[] emp;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
    public string deptname;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct empDetails
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string empname;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int empid;
}
```

I'm sending it through sockets

```
structures.DeptDetails Details = new structures.DeptDetails();
Details.depid = 123;
Details.noemp= 3;
Details.emp= new structures.empDetails[Details.noemp];

Details.emp[0].empname= "xyz"; 
Details.emp[0].empid= 1;

Details.scrips[1].empname="abc"
Details.scrips[1].empid = 2;

Details.scrips[2].empname= "pqr"
Details.scrips[2].empid= 6;

Details.deptname= "PYTHON";
int bytesSend = senderSock.Send(MainModule.struc.StructureToByteArray(Details));
```

`StructureToByteArray` Method contains:

```
public byte[] StructureToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```

But I'm unable to send data...
my exception is:

> Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845514/error-type-could-not-be-marshaled-because-the-length-of-an-embedded-array-inst?

Comment: i gone through that link but cannot relate it how to solve my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is very clear:

> ...the **length of an embedded array** instance does not match the **declared length** in the layout

Hence, you've instantiated an array with different size than declared (declared 8, instantiated 3), therefore it can't be marshaled.

Comment: Thanks alot...Your answer helped me